# Что хранит в себе неинициализированная переменная в C#?

Tags: c#, переменные

Собственно вопрос и состоит в этом:
Что хранить в себе неинициализированная переменная в C#?
Насколько я знаю, в С++ такие переменные хранят всякий "мусор", в Java null, а для C# не нашел информации, кроме как "выдаст ошибку"

Comment: Стоит, наверное, дать более точное определение "инициализации". В С++, например, все переменные инициализированы, но это инициализированное значение может быть неопределённым в некоторых ситуациях

Comment: @dIm0n, я имею ввиду, например, когда пишем просто int a или string stroka, что они в себе хранят? Вообще, в другом месте мне ответили, что "в C# нет переменных, есть структуры, они в себе не хранят ничего, а программа вызывает исключение", верно?

Comment: Подождите ответа от знающих C# (это не я :)). Я просто уточнил, что с точки зрения С++ нет неинициализированных переменных, как сказано у вас в вопросе

Comment: Узнать легко, вот например для `int`: `Console.WriteLine(default(int).ToString());`

Comment: "Всякий мусор" - это обычно то, что хранила другая переменная, которая "жила" до того в этом месте. В C++ таким образом можно подсмотреть или даже поменять "чужие" данные или даже код, что очень небезопасно, поэтому в современных языках подходят строже к таким вещам и среда выполнения инициализирует значения переменных в любом случае.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Неинициализированным переменным присваиваются [значения по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values), а именно:

- для ссылочных типов: `null`;
- для встроенных числовых типов (`int`, `double` и т.п.): 0
- для `bool`: `false`
- для `char`: `\0`
- для перечислений: значение выражения `(E)0`, где `E` — тип перечисления;
- для структур: значение, созданное путем установки всем полям значений по умолчанию;
- для `Nullable`: экземпляр, свойство `HasValue` которого имеет значение `false`, а свойство `Value` не определено.

Значение по-умолчанию для типа можно определить с помощью [оператора `default`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator):

```
int a = default(int);
```

Также, начиная с C# 7.1 можно использовать [литерал `default`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) для присвоения значений переменным:

```
int a = default;
```

Comment: Я бы дополнил про `default(T)` практическим примером.

Comment: @aepot OK, добавил, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В языке C# неинициализированнае переменные не хранят в себе ничего, поскольку язык не позволяет читать из таких переменных.

Comment: Дельное замечание, но это верно только для локальных переменных. Сравнение с Java навело на мысль что речь идет о переменных класса.

Comment: @defaultlocale "переменная класса" называется "поле"

Answer (score -1):

C# является языком со статической типизацией. Это значит, что при создании переменной обязательно определяется тип хранящихся в ней данных, и этот тип нельзя изменить в ходе программы. (Исключение - тип dynamic)

Почитай тут - https://brainoteka.com/blogs/c-spravochnik/peremennie-c

Comment: Да, я понимаю, меня интересует, что будет в себе хранить, например, пустая int a или пустой string name

Comment: @authoraytee null

Comment: Вопрос про инициализацию, а вы пишите про типы